# Fancybox - javascript to detect mobile orientation and launch advisory pop-up if portrait

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I've got the fancybox pop-up to launch OK, but for now only in response to:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 400 && window.innerHeight < 600)
```

See example here: [www.casedasole.it/testing/popup.html](http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup.html)

If you reload the page at less than 400px width, the popup pops up.

But what I need is to change the "if" to whatever indicates that the mobile is in portrait mode. Then the pop-up will say something like: "This website looks better in landscape".
I've found references to `orientationchange` events, but nothing yet that works for detecting whether a mobile is in portrait and, if so, launching the pop-up.
The code now is:

```
if (window.innerWidth < 400 && window.innerHeight < 600)   
{$.fancybox.open([
    {
        href : 'http://www.casedasole.it/images/jarac.jpg'
    }
], {
        padding : 0
}   
);}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/aV9V3/)***

What you should really do is just check the width and height of the window. If the width is > than the height then it is landscape. If the height is more than the width then it is portrait.

```
if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight)//portait
if (window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight)//landscape
```

*edit*

Should just be

```
var isPortrait = window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight;
if( isPortrait )
{
 $.fancybox.open([
   {
    href : 'http://www.casedasole.it/images/jarac.jpg'
   }
  ], {
   padding : 0
   }   
 );
}
```

Comment: Bravo! It works - http://www.casedasole.it/testing/popup2.html - I'll do some testing with mobiles now

Comment: @plugincontainer - That's okay :) You can accept it if it solved your question though.

Comment: @plugincontainer : I will upvote for you so you could do that too ;)

Comment: thanks, done (says here "more to go", meaning words?)

Comment: @plugincontainer Yeah a comment must be a certain amount of characters. 15 I think

Answer (score 1):

I use to compare `width` against `height` and works not only for mobile but desktop browsers too, however if you really want to filter mobile devices, then compare features instead.

This is what I normally do :

```
// detect mobile devices that support touch screen feature
// including windows mobile devices
var isTouchSupported = 'ontouchstart' in window,
    isTouchSupportedIE10 = navigator.userAgent.match(/Touch/i) != null;

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    if (isTouchSupported || isTouchSupportedIE10) {
        // this is a mobile device
        if (window.orientation == 0 || window.orientation == 180) {
            // run init for portrait orientation
        } else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
            // run init for landscape orientation
        }
        // detect orientation changes
        window.addEventListener("orientationchange", function () {
            if (window.orientation === 0 || window.orientation === 180) {
                // changed to portrait
            } else if (window.orientation == 90 || window.orientation == -90) {
                // changed to landscape
            }
        }, false);

    } else {
        // this is desktop device
        // run init for desktops here
    }
}); // ready
```